# Binding a ComboBox selection to the background color of a border.

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox, element

Please forgive my ignorance. I am new to vb.net and WPF. I have a comboBox that has a list of colors like this. By the way this is in WPF.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    cmbColors.ItemsSource = GetType(Colors).GetProperties()
End Sub
```

In the XAML the comboBox is created as follows:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbColors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,35,0,0" 
          Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding  Name}" Width="16" Height="16" 
                           Margin="0,2,5,2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="cmbColorsText" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

What I'm trying to do is when the program is run start with a beginning background color of grey, and when a new background color is selected from the comboBox the back ground will update. 
Here's the XAML of the element that I'm trying to bind to the selection.

```
<Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding Text, ElementName=cmbColors}">
    <TextBlock Text="PRACTICE" Style="{StaticResource linkButtons}"/>
```

I have gone through every (string) type in the property window for the border>background>create binding>Element>comboBox and for some reason (that I can't determine) I have either missed the appropriate one or am looking at this the wrong way.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the comboBox works as intended. The only issue I am having is getting the border background to change color based on selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the `Background` to a string, but the Background will need a ColorBrush. So, if your combo `ItemsSource` already contains items that are of ColorBrush then you can just bind to `SelectedItem` rather than `Text`.

Or you can use a converter in your Background binding, that takes the string and returns a `SolidColorBrush`, say.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the binding to Background="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmbColors} and it still does not work. I'm not real comfortable in adding a converter, I think that would create more problems at my current skill level.

Comment: As I say, binding to SelectedItem will only work if the type of items in your Combo are of the correct type (SolidColorBrush, say). But if your combo is full of just Colors (i.e. not Brushes) then it won't work. And converters are great, and very useful for binding. Find a nice easy tutorial that covers them and you won't look back!

Answer (score 0):

Change the binding to

```
<Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=cmbColors}">
            <TextBlock  Text="PRACTICE" Style="{StaticResource linkButtons}"/>
```

The Text property of the ComboBox is returning the result of the ToString() method of the PropertyInfo object, so for instance if you select Black, it will be "System.Windows.Media.Color Black" and won't be parsed as a valid color.